# Why Spring Kafka listener is not able to consume message sent from CLI but is able to consume when using KafkaTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to follow the [docs](https://value) about serialization/deserialization, and I don't understand why I don't receive message when producing from CLI:

```
docker exec -it broker1 kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic order.created --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=@
>"123"@{"orderId":"bfd9ebf3-0218-49dd-bc3e-dcd172ec3647"}
```

When using `KafkaTemplate` I do receive message:

```
@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(){
    kafkaTemplate.send("order.created", "123", new OrderCreated());
    return "sent";
}
```

Here is my `.yaml` config:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    banner-mode: 'off'
  profiles:
    active: default
  application:
    name: kafka-experimental
  jackson.default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL
  kafka:
    admin:
      fail-fast: true
    consumer:
      group-id: order-group
      #DOCS:
      #When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the poll() returns.
      #To solve this problem, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer has been introduced. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value).
      #If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer returns a null value and a DeserializationException in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes.
      #If the ConsumerRecord contains a DeserializationException header for either the key or value, the container’s ErrorHandler is called with the failed ConsumerRecord. The record is not passed to the listener.
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      auto-startup: true
      max-poll-records: 500
      properties:
        acks: all
        allow.auto.create.topics: true
        partition.assignment.strategy: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor
        #key delegate is -> spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer #does not work with: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        #value delegate is -> spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        #spring.json.value.default.type:
        #spring.json.use.type.headers: true
        spring.json.trusted.packages: "*"
      security.protocol: "PLAINTEXT"
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    bootstrap-servers:
      - http://localhost:9092
```

As for `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`, I think its working. If I send `new Student()` via template, then listener is not triggered, but I do see message on the topic with `--from-beginning`.

Here is the listener:

```
        @KafkaListener(
            clientIdPrefix = "OrderCreatedHandlerReceiver",
            id = "orderConsumerClient",
            topics = "order.created",
            groupId = "order-group",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) Integer partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY) String key,
            @Payload OrderCreated payload,
            @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
        log.info("Received Kafka message: payload={} with key={} on partition={}", payload, key, partition);
}
```

Adding `docker-compose.yaml` with the broker config:

```
version: '3.8'
name: "kafka-experimental-cluster"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    hostname: broker1
    container_name: broker1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1 # value 1 if we have single broker in a cluster. This is a topic to track consumer's offset. If its value is one and kafka node goes down, we lose information where should consumer read from. That's way this values is larger than one, depending on how many brokers we have
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1 #use when replica and leader (so two in total, {leader+replica=2} must acknowledge message acceptance
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1 #1 for dev and 3 in prod
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 3000 # When consumers are being added to group, each time a new consumer arrives in consumer group,
        # a re-balance is initiated. Consumers often don’t all start up at the same time resulting in many re-balances.
        # As each re-balance has to go through the initialization and close phases, it can become a lengthy process to get an application into a steady running state.
        # Adding a configurable delay to the initial re-balance of a new, or empty, consumer group,
      # can significantly reduce number of re-balances. For test 0 for prod 3000
      #auto.create.topics.enable false test with spring startup
      AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS: true
      KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: producer
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
```

Comment: Since it works from `KafkaTemplate`, it is highly likely that there are some issues in how the data is formatted or sent over via the CLI. Maybe some deserialization errors happen and the container fails to deliver the message to the handler method?

Comment: Hi, I haven't noticed any error logs in the container nor in the application logs. I've added docker-compose I'm using. It is an image from Confluent.

Comment: If you have a simple app with the docker image for Kafka you are using, we can try it on our end.